# How subscribe to a standard LWC components message channel

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have been able to get the message channel functionality working for my LWC components. I can have multiple custom components on the same page and they are able to talk to each other without a problem. The message channel information is posted here -

[Communicate Across the DOM with Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel)

Now I would like to receive messages from standard LWC components so that my custom components can be in the same app page and react based on user interactions with these components.

For example I have a page with two components. The standard Account record detail component is on the left and my custom component is on the right. In this example I would like my custom component to show contact details for the account that has been loaded in the left component.

[image: Standard and custom component]

I am assuming that these standard events exist on the standard Salesforce components. I cannot find any documentation on how this might work so do not even know if it is possible.

Does anybody know if this is possible, and if so what events we can subscribe to and where that information exists?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I feel it should be possible so wonder if I am looking in the wrong place!

Comment: you are not looking at the wrong place. its currently not possible in salesforce via standard methods. You can use Wire service to get the objects field values in your lwc and that seems to get called everytime there is an update on that object. its not very straight forward but it works